# Get the last parent name from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, pgadmin

My objetive is get the top name and levelid of each level row.

Like the image below, In the top_level_name column at the first row should be filled with: "(103432,'282 ..."

In the second row, top_level_name should be: "Corrrea CV-130"

In 6: "146"

And so on...

[image]

How can I do that?

I have this table named "level"

[image]

And another named "rootlevel":

[image: level table]

[image]

The level parentid column is the child levelid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your query as a table expression to pre-compute the joins, and then use a `CASE` clause to find the top level name.

For example:

```
select *,
  case when "level7.name" is not null then "level7.name"
       when "level6.name" is not null then "level6.name"
       when "level5.name" is not null then "level5.name"
       when "level4.name" is not null then "level4.name"
       when "level3.name" is not null then "level3.name"
       when "level2.name" is not null then "level2.name"
       when "level.name" is not null then "level.name"
  end as top_level_name
from (
  -- your select here
) x
```

Comment: It gets me this error: 

ERROR:  CASE types level and character varying cannot be matched
LINE 4:        when "level_5.name" is not null then "level_5.name"
                                                    ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 173

Comment: Its weird becouse if I remove the line "level_7.name is not null ..." and line "when level_6 ..." it works but if I dont remove that It gets me the error

Comment: @Braven Works for me. See running example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQzyoA97paa7YZtrTc2a3F/0.

Comment: It was my error. Sorry. Your solution worked. Thanks a lot!